# How would I resolve this TypeError that I'm getting with Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have this code here

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listener.bind(("192.168.56.101", 4444))
listener.listen(0)
print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
connection, address = listener.accept()
print("[+] Got a Connection from" + str(address))

while True:
    command = input(">> ")
    connection.send(command.encode('utf-8'))  # Encode the string to bytes before sending
    result = connection.recv(1024)
    result = result.decode('utf-8')
    print(result)
```

But when I run this, I get this TypeError

```
[+] Waiting for incoming connections
[+] Got a Connection from('xxx.xxx.xx.xxx', 53505)
>> dir
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/PyProjects/Windows/listener.py", line 16, in <module>
    connection.send(command)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I repair my code to not throw this error?

As you can see in the code examples, I tried using .encode and .decode, however, that has not worked

Comment: Looks like you didn't save the file. In source code you correctly `.encode()`d the `command` but in error message it says you didn't.